# To find number of hours between start date and end date in excel or power bi?

Tags: excel, powerbi-desktop

I have a data having two date columns. SHUT HOURS column I calculate after subtracting FEEDON from FEEDOFF date.  I need the information for number of shut hours on each day. If I just subtract FEEDON from FEEDOFF, it will give me total number of hours for all days. But I want for each day. Is there any way where I can  find number of SHUT HOURS on each day from FEEDOFF and FEEDON date?[image]

The output I want is in the following picture. For example, for first row I want all dates in different cells corresponding to different number of hours. Is there any way to do that?

[image]

Comment: It would help if you gave an example of the results you want to achieve. 72 is not the number you want; what is it, then?

Comment: Hi... 72 is total number of hours from 19/09/2020 to 22/09/2020. What I want is  number of hours on 19/09/2020, 20/09/2020 , 21/09/2020 and 22/09/2020. Is there any way to do that? or Am I lacking some information?

Comment: Yes, you're missing out on telling us what that would look like in your Excel grid. Where would all these results go, if there are a varying number of days between two dates? For example your row with 714 hours. What should that look like? Mock it up manually for your data sample. Then edit your question and add a screenshot of that mock-up.

Comment: by definition, if a shutdown spans more than two dates, the middle days would always have 24 hours. You may only need to calculate the first and the last day individually.

Comment: Hii....Is there any formula in excel to calculate this?

Comment: No, this can't be done with a formula (well, nothing is impossible, but it will be very tricky and not error-proof, and you will need extra columns etc...). you'll need VBA for this.

Answer (score 0):

This is ARRAY (CSE) formula. Press Control+Shift+Enter after pasting the formula.

Formula in G1 is

```
=ABS(IF(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$4,"<="&E1+86399/86400,$B$2:$B$4,">="&E1)>0,1,0)*IFERROR(IF(MATCH(E1,INT($A$2:$A$4),0)=MATCH(E1,INT($B$2:$B$4),0),INDEX($B$2:$B$4,MATCH(E1,INT($B$2:$B$4),0),1)-INDEX($A$2:$A$4,MATCH(E1,INT($A$2:$A$4),0),1),""),IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$4,MATCH(E1,INT($A$2:$A$4),0),1)-E1-1,1)*IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$4,MATCH(E1,INT($B$2:$B$4),0),1)-E1,1))*24)
```

Pasting again being too long to scroll

`=ABS(IF(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$4,"<="&E1+86399/86400,$B$2:$B$4,">="&E1)>0,1,0)*IFERROR(IF(MATCH(E1,INT($A$2:$A$4),0)=MATCH(E1,INT($B$2:$B$4),0),INDEX($B$2:$B$4,MATCH(E1,INT($B$2:$B$4),0),1)-INDEX($A$2:$A$4,MATCH(E1,INT($A$2:$A$4),0),1),""),IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$4,MATCH(E1,INT($A$2:$A$4),0),1)-E1-1,1)*IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$4,MATCH(E1,INT($B$2:$B$4),0),1)-E1,1))*24)`

[image]

Got help from [this link](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/check-if-date-ranges-falls-within-specific-dates.1070739/)

This will fail if the dates are overlapping as in case of your fourth row is overlapping the first and the third.

Comment: Note that if the answer is 6.50 then it is 6 hours 30 minutes and not 6 hours 50 minutes.